# Handle ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification for Facebook & Twitter in iOS 6+

Tags: facebook, twitter, ios6, user-accounts, social-framework

I am using Social framework for Facebook & Twitter integration. For this I followed this [link](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-6-tutorial-integrating-facebook-your-applications)
Everything is working fine except when I app receives ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification , it crashes.
App crashes when

1) I installed app for first time & user don't have Facebook / Twitter account configured in Settings.

2) When I call any method of Facebook / Twitter , it gives me error code 6 as I don't have account configured which is right.

3) I click on HOME button so my app enters background & add account in Settigs.

4) Once I configured account & come back to app , my app launches from background & receives ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification.

5) In selector of ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification my account object is nil so my app crashes. So I checked for the nil

Here is my code

```
    #pragma mark - Request Facebook Account Access

-(void)requestFacebookAccountAccess
{
    requestType = kNoOpRequest;
    //  Register for Account Change notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accountChanged:) name:ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    // Set facebook permissions
    NSArray *permissions = nil;

    // We need to ask for Basic permission first
    if (![kUserDefaults boolForKey:FACEBOOK_BASIC_PERMISSION]) {
        permissions = @[@"email",@"user_about_me",@"user_location",@"friends_about_me"];
        self.isBasicFacebookPermissionsRequested = YES;
    }
    else {
        permissions = @[@"email",@"user_about_me",@"user_location",@"friends_about_me",@"publish_stream"];
    }

    //use ACAccountStore to help create your dictionary
    NSDictionary *dictFacebook = @{
        ACFacebookAppIdKey: kFacebookAppIDKey,
        ACFacebookPermissionsKey: permissions,
        ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
    };

    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFacebook completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {

            if (self.isBasicFacebookPermissionsRequested) {
                self.isBasicFacebookPermissionsRequested = NO;
                [kUserDefaults saveBasicFacebookPermissionsGrantedStatus:YES];
                //[self requestFacebookAccountAccess];
            }

            // User granted permission to Accout
            NSArray *accountsArray = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];

            if ([accountsArray count]>0) {
                //It will always be the last object with SSO
                self.facebookAccount = [accountsArray lastObject];
                NSLog(@"In %s::IS MAIN THREAD:- %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[NSThread isMainThread]?@"YES":@"NO");

                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFacebookAccountAccessGranted)]) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                            [self.delegate didFacebookAccountAccessGranted];
                        });
                }
            }
            else {
                [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:@"You don't have any Facebook accounts set up yet.Please set a Facebbok account and try again."];
            }
        }
        else {
            DLog(@"User denied permission to Accout::Localized Error:- %@",error.localizedDescription);
            if([error code]==6) {
                [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:@"Please setup facebook account from Settings"];
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFacebookAccountAccessDenied:)]) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                        [self.delegate didFacebookAccountAccessDenied:error];
                    });
                }
            }
            else if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFacebookAccountAccessDenied:)]) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    [self.delegate didFacebookAccountAccessDenied:error];
                });
            }

            else {
                // User denied permission to Account
                [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"User denied permission to Accout::Error:- %@",error.localizedDescription]];
            }
        }
    }];
}



#pragma mark - Get Logged In User Info

-(void)getLoggedInUserInfo
{
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SELECT current_location,uid,name,sex,birthday,email,pic FROM user WHERE uid=me()",@"q", nil];
    requestType = kGetLoggedInUserInfoRequest;
    [self requestDataUsingURL:requestURL parameters:dict requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET];
}

#pragma mark - Request Data From Facebook

-(void)requestDataUsingURL:(NSURL*)requestURL parameters:(NSDictionary*)params requestMethod:(SLRequestMethod)reuqestMethod
{

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:reuqestMethod
                                                      URL:requestURL
                                               parameters:params];
    request.account = self.facebookAccount;

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                         NSError *error)
     {
         NSDictionary *dictData =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         if(!error)
         {
             if([dictData objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
             {
                 DLog(@"Request Data From Facebook Errro:- %@",dictData);
                 [self attemptRenewCredentials];
                 if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetFacebookError:)]) {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                         [self.delegate didGetFacebookError:dictData];
                     });
                 }
             }
             else {
                // Process the response
                //NSLog(@"Response Dictionary contains: %@", dictData );
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didPostToFacebook:)]) {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                         [self.delegate didPostToFacebook:dictData];
                     });
                }
             }
         }
         else{
             if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetFacebookError:)]) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                     [self.delegate didGetFacebookError:dictData];
                 });
             }
             else {
                 [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:@"Some error occured while processing Facebook request"];
             }
         }

     }];
}

-(void)accountChanged:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    if (self.facebookAccount!=nil) {
        [self attemptRenewCredentials];
    }
    else {
        [self requestFacebookAccountAccess];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Attempt to Renew Credentials

-(void)attemptRenewCredentials
{
    [self.accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:(ACAccount *)self.facebookAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error){
        if(!error)
        {
            switch (renewResult) {
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed:
                    NSLog(@"Good to go");
                    [self againRequestFacebook];
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected:
                    NSLog(@"User declined permission");
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed:
                    NSLog(@"non-user-initiated cancel, you may attempt to retry");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        else{
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from renew credentials%@",error);
        }
    }];
}

-(void)againRequestFacebook
{
    switch (requestType) {
        case kGetLoggedInUserInfoRequest:
            [self getLoggedInUserInfo];
            break;
        case kGetFriendsInfoRequest:
            [self getFacebookFriendsInfo];
            break;
        case kPostToWallRequest:
            [self postToFacebookWallInBackgroundForUserId:fbUserIdForPost withParams:paramsToPost];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Remove Observer for Notification

-(void)dealloc
{
    requestType = kNoOpRequest;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification];
}
```

But accountChanged method gets called multiple times. 
What is wrong in this ? How can I handle this situation ?
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same problem...so i used a work around by having a BOOL value in NSUserDefaults to execute accountChanged method only once

```
-(void)accountChanged:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    BOOL calledAccountChanged =[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:DidAccountChanged] boolValue];
    if(!calledAccountChanged)
    {
        if (self.facebookAccount!=nil) {
            [self attemptRenewCredentials];
        }
        else {
            [self requestFacebookAccountAccess];
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can change DidAccountChanged value later in the code...

If you have better solution do post it...

Comment: Thanks for reply. What should we do if user changed the account daily ? Where should we reset the calledAccountChanged ?

Comment: `-(void)accountChanged:(NSNotification *)notif` this method will only be called if facebook account is changed and the app is in the background. If you close the App, change the FB account and open the App again, the notification wont work. What am doing is, store the FB UID in **NSUserDefaults**, when the App is opened, Check if the stored FB UID matches with current one. If it doesnt match change `calledAccountChanged`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try this & let you know.

Comment: @SaravanaVijay Please look upon this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316770/new-facebook-account-in-ios-6-settings and help me out.