# new facebook account in iOS 6 settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using following code to access the facebook

```
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:TRUE];
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"email",
                        nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:true    
completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }
    else
        {

 }];
```

It is working fine when user has enabled the facebook account in iOS setting and also when there is no account enabled in iOS settings then it goes to safari for facebook authentication. But suppose user has first enabled the account with abcd@gmail.com and then after some time he has added new account i.e. efgh@gmail.com. So how the app come to know that user has changed his/her account in iOS settings. How to check it by using facebook SDK. Anyone has idea?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

The information (access token, etc) stored inside a FBSession is entirely independent of any other account authority (this includes iOS6, Safari, or the Facebook app). Those other authorities are only used to connect your app, once it's connected, your app operates independently. This means that even if the user logs out, and logs in again with a different id, it doesn't affect your app at all. The user of your app needs to proactively log out inside your app, and initiate another login in order to change accounts.

This is why it's vitally important that the user has a way of identifying themselves inside of your app (either through a profile picture, and/or their name displayed somewhere), so they know which account they're using.