# ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification is called repeatedly

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook in my ios application to post score.While logging into facebook i check whether facebook account is configured in my iPhone setting, if it is not configured i give a message as "Configure your facebook login in iphone setting".
So when the user configures it i get a notification my app by using "**`ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification`**".
My problem is this notification is called several times even if user has changed account only once

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sharingStatus) name:ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

This is how i have registered notification

```
- (void)sharingStatus {
i give message as account being configured.

}
```

Can anyone please help me why the notification `ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification` is getting called several times. I followed this link [Handle ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification for Facebook & Twitter in iOS 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982622/handle-acaccountstoredidchangenotification-for-facebook-twitter-in-ios-6) but was not that useful to me.
Thank you

Comment: Can you please mention where are you adding the Observer. Faced the same issue. Tried to add observer at application:
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

But still it fired so many times. So i added the observer whenever app goes background before that removing the already added observer.

Comment: I couldn't get to make ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification work. As I understand, I just need to add [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accountChanged:) name:ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil]; and the method accountChanged:(NSNotification *)notification right?